# SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() Always Returns 1

Tags: sql-server

I'm using this query:

```
INSERT INTO [LepidoliteDB].[dbo].[EGelLayerWeighingData] ([EGelWeighingDataID], [Amount], [ContainerID], [Portions],
[PortionNumber], [Canceled], [LayerID], [WeighingDone], [InsertDone],
[MeasuresDone], [StartDateAndTime], [EndDateAndTime]) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

But `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` always returns 1.

What am I missing?

Comment: have you checked that you have set your id key as a primary key?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant in your scenario, but just wanted to know which column in the mentioned table have you actually defined as an "Identity" column?

Comment: If you run that in SQL Server Management Studio it will fail. Are you running this inside an application? Please post all of the code involved. Also indicate which column is defined as the identity column

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - why it will fail in SSMS?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid
I'm using this queries with vb.net TableAdapters.
My Primery key is "ID" field with Identity specification (NOT EGelWeighingDataID Field).
I'm using Sql Server Management Studio 2012.

Comment: @marc_s - even if run this query in different database rather than actual database. It will work. I already tried and tested it, it will definitely work.

Comment: Do you have to use ODBC? ODBC can mess up scope_identity  depending on how you execute the query.

Comment: @rajeshmpanchal, When I run that I get `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near '?'.` because `?` is not valid in SSMS. You need to put a literal value in. @Hile please post your vb code as well. Particularly how you are retrieving the scope_identity value.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - Very funny man, he has just copied the ready query from SSMS, nothing else. I thought he will replace it with some string. btw in that case you are abs right. ;)

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is..... they have not posted the 'full story' here. Adjusted SQL will probably return the identity fine. There is most likely some issue in the VB.Net code that extracts the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to write it is ..

```
RETURN  SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

You can also use `@@IDENTITY` and `IDENT_CURRENT` for this

SCOPE_IDENTITY, IDENT_CURRENT, and @@IDENTITY are similar functions because they return values that are inserted into identity columns.

IDENT_CURRENT is not limited by scope and session; it is limited to a specified table. IDENT_CURRENT returns the value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope. For more information, see IDENT_CURRENT (Transact-SQL).

SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY return the last identity values that are generated in any table in the current session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns values inserted only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope.

Therefore  RETURN  SCOPE_IDENTITY() is the best one.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have an instead-of / for trigger there? what version of MSSQL are you using? Have you tried doing this without a database name? Have you tried this with a begin-end block?

Have you read this article [@@IDENTITY vs SCOPE_IDENTITY() vs IDENT_CURRENT](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but I was having this same issue, and I managed to solve it by going into my XSD and on the query, changing the ExecuteMode of the query from NonQuery to Scalar.  This stopped it always returning 1 and instead returning the ID of the previously added row.

It was probably down to me trying to add the SELECT to the INSERT afterwards, rather than doing it all at once and the UI making it correctly for me.

Comment: a silly mistake, for those using ado.net, you have to ExecuteScalar, Execute returns the number of affected rows

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and I must admit it was a dumb mistake, but I thought it may happen to someone else.  I was using the Execute command that returns the number of rows affected instead of a Query command.

By the way, I was combining my Insert and SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() together in one command, which is why I started with the Execute command.  I was still able to combine them, but I used ExecuteScalar instead.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the thread, but if someone is using Dapper ORM and they are doing an UPDATE or INSERT a single row and want to know the primary key of that updated record:

```
var connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");

string sql=@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] ([Name],[Subject])
VALUES (@Name,@Subject)
SET @StudentId=CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)";
```

For the above SQL string, if you execute the SQL connection like:

```
Result=connection.Execute(sql,new {Name,Subject});
```

The value of **Result** will be the number of rows affected, in this case only one since we have inserted only one row.
Instead do this:

```
Result=connection.Query<int>(sql,new {Name,Subject}).Single();
```

Now **Result** will have the primary key value of the newly inserted/updated column.

Remember, this answer is only relevant to single row insertion/update